# Create list from values of a dictionary using a list containing the order of the keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary which contains a certain number of key/value pairs such as:

```
d = { "v1": 1, "v2": 2, "v3":3, "v4": 4 }
```

and a list containing the keys in a certain order:

```
l = [ "v2", "v3", "v1", "v4" ]
```

how can I obtain a list of values using the order of `l` in an elegant way ?

```
[ 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

The only thing I could think of is:

```
[ d[k] for k in l ]
```

Same question if I wanted to obtain a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.x , try using -

```
>>> d = { "v1": 1, "v2": 2, "v3":3, "v4": 4 }
>>> l = [ "v2", "v3", "v1", "v4" ]
>>> map(d.get,l)
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

If you are using Python 3.x , `map` function returns a `map` object which you can iterate over, for converting to list use `list` function , Example -

```
>>> list(map(d.get,l))
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Remove the list() to make this even better in Python 2.

Comment: map returns a `map object` over which we can iterate, tried in Python 3.x though

Comment: `map()` returns a `list` in Python 2 and a `map` in Python 3.

Comment: Edited the answer to include that as well.

Comment: Since the question is for python 2.7 , update the 2.x version first and then the 3.x version as a side note